# Regular expression to limit input in textbox via HTML

Tags: html, regex

I have a textbox and i want the input for the textbox to satisfy to conditions:
a) It should be a number
b) It be should be greater than 5.
What should be the regular expression for that?

Comment: try this. [6-9][0-9]*

Comment: you can check the number is valid or not like here : `(([1-5]\d|[6-9]))$` [see the test results here](https://regex101.com/r/vX3dU0/7)

Comment: @DineshSuthar How would this allow for a number such as 28?

Comment: @RahulHendawe How would this allow for a number such as 8214? Also, why the double parentheses?

Comment: Can you more spefic?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `regex` you can use `<input type='number'`... Check snippet below

```html
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="6" />
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, I think it is a worthy answer.

Comment: @DucFilan  Ya its not working if we directly enter the number.

Comment: @AarthnaMaheshwari it automatically validate the value on `submit or blur` event. You can check.

Comment: @DucFilan This kind of specification will be supported by the most browsers, including the old ones.

Comment: It's not supported in IE<10.

Comment: @DucFilan it Support all major browsers which you can check in following link `http://caniuse.com/#search=number`.

Comment: I said IE < 10.

Comment: If you would like to watch the global stats of browser usage, you will see, that the IE<10 will be used by a very small percentage of all Browser users. This is a unimportant share. Here is the statistics: [W3Counter](https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)